# get month from the datetime in MSSQL using knexjs

Tags: sql-server, node.js, knex.js

I develop a web-based system using nodejs and knexjs for the things related to the database. I have a problem when I tried to get the data from the database using knexjs for the data at the specific month. Normally, I can use `Month(date)` to get the month of the date from the database using raw sql. Here is my query in knexjs:

```
.where('Month(message_time)',(new Date()).getMonth()+1)
```

The error message said that the column is invalid.

```
Unhandled rejection RequestError: Invalid column name 'Month(message_time)'.
```

All the help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please post the exact error message you are getting. Do `isNusantara` and `message_time` exist as columns in your table?

Comment: Yes, both columns exist. I just updated the error message

Comment: I'm no expert in knex, but what happens if you remove the MONTH() bit? Is it possible it simply cannot handle a function used in the `.Where` part of the code?

Comment: What is the datatype of `message_time`?

Comment: the datatype is datetime

Answer (score 4):

Anytime you're using a function, like `MONTH`, you should use a "raw" statement:

```
.whereRaw('Month(message_time) = ?', [(new Date()).getMonth()+1])
```

You can read more about raw statements and parameter binding [here](http://knexjs.org/#Raw-Bindings).